# How to save SQLite table in CSV using Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to export some SQLite table data.  I'm getting the IOException: /TestFileExport0719a.csv: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)

Below is my code:

```
 Boolean returnCode = false;
        int i = 0;
        String csvValues = "";

        dbadapter = new DBAdapter(this);
        dbadapter.open();
        try {
            File outFile = new File(outFileName);
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(outFile);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
            Cursor cursor = dbadapter.getAllSkus();
            if (cursor != null) {
                   while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                     csvValues = Long.toString(cursor.getLong(0)) + ",";
                        csvValues += cursor.getString(1)
                                + ",";
                        csvValues +=  cursor.getString(2)
                                + "\n";

                            out.write(csvValues);

                    }
                cursor.close();
            }
            out.close();
            returnCode = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            returnCode = false;
            Log.d(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        dbadapter.close();
        return returnCode;
```

The devices are not rooted. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

I get the following error after I made the change to:

File outFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), outFileName);

07-20 18:31:07.595: D/BackupCSV(1580): IOException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/TestFileExport0719a.csv: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Edit-

Adding the permission in the manifest fixed the problem.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Adding the permission fixed the problem.  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future, please post the entire stack trace.

Assuming that `outFileName` is `TestFileExport0719a.csv`, that is an invalid path. You need to write to either your portion of internal storage (e.g., `getFilesDir()`) or external storage (e.g., `getExternalFilesDir()`).

Since this is an export operation, I would assume you want to write to external storage, so the user can access the CSV file independently. In that case, change:

```
File outFile = new File(outFileName);
```

to:

```
File outFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(), outFileName);
```

or:

```
File outFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), outFileName);
```

or something like that.